# URL in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have problem to display clickable link in django admin panel next to 'icon' field or add help_text witch will be clickable and if i click on it, it must open this 'https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons' website in new window of browther .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MImcr.png)

link example :   https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons

I tried this  but nothing happens, it shows just normal models without link and text.

**admin.py  **

```
from .models import RaffleGame
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import admin

class RaffleGameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('icon', 'link_to_google')

    def link_to_google(self, obj):
        url = 'https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons'
        link_text = 'click me for more info'
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, link_text)

    link_to_google.short_description = 'Mehr Icons findest du hier'


admin.site.register(RaffleGame, RaffleGameAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
class RaffleGame(models.Model):

    class GameStatus(models.TextChoices):
        scheduled = 'scheduled'
        announced = 'announced'
        draw_day = 'draw_day'
        drawn = 'drawn'
        finished = 'finished'

    class IconColor(models.TextChoices):
        red = 'red'
        yellow = 'yellow'
        black = 'black'
        green = 'green'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='PiA-Gewinnspiel', verbose_name='Titel')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GameStatus.choices,
                              default=GameStatus.scheduled, verbose_name='Status', editable=False)
    announcement_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Spiel ankündigen ab')
    draw_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Zeitpunkt der Auslosung')
    finished_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Gewinner anzeigen bis')
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='park', verbose_name='Icon')
    icon_color = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=IconColor.choices,
                                  default=IconColor.black, verbose_name='Icon Farbe')
    icon_outlined = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Icon outlined')
   



    class Meta:
        db_table = "RaffleGame"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Do you want the link to go specifcly to the URL you have given or it should display the icon link dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `custom widget` class that will extend the default `TextInput` widget for Icon fields and adds the icon link next to the text box.
Here is the custom widget class you need to add to your `admin.py` file.

```
#import TextInput class
from django.forms import TextInput
    #Custom Widget Class
class IconTextInput(TextInput):
      def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
          html = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
          return html + ' <a href="https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons&icon.query='+value+'&selected=Material+Icons+Outlined:'+value+':" target="_blank">' + value + '</a>'
```

In this custom widget class, I have inherited the Django TextInput class and updated the render method as per your need.

Next, You need to add this custom widget class with your RaffleGameAdmin class. You need to import models from django.db before that.

```
from django.db import models
class RaffleGameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            formfield_overrides = {
                models.CharField: {'widget': IconTextInput},
            }
            ...
```

So here is the full code you need to add on your admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from .models import RaffleGame
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.forms import TextInput


class IconTextInput(TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        return html + ' <a href="https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons&icon.query='+value+'&selected=Material+Icons+Outlined:'+value+':" target="_blank">' + value + '</a>'


class RaffleGameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': IconTextInput},
    }
    list_display = ('icon', 'link_to_google')

    def link_to_google(self, obj):
        url = 'https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons'
        link_text = 'click me for more info'
        return format_html('<a href="{}" target="_blank">{}</a>', url, link_text)

    link_to_google.short_description = 'Mehr Icons findest du hier'

admin.site.register(RaffleGame, RaffleGameAdmin)
```

With this, you will achieve your goal what you wanted.
Also note, I displayed the icon name aside the textfield and when click it will go to specific icon page with dynamic URL. For example if the icon name is home it will go to: [https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons&icon.query=home&selected=Material+Icons+Outlined:home:](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material%20Icons&icon.query=home&selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined:home:)

**And here is a screenshot how it will look after implementing the code above.**

[image]

**Please note the browser hover URL it's dynamic which will open in a new tab when click and works for any valid icon added to the `Raffle games` Table.**